# Tuning the hyperparameter with gridsearch results in overfitting

Tags: python, xgboost, grid-search, hyperparameters

Tuning the hyperparameter with gridsearch results in overfitting.

The train error is definitely low, but the test error is high. Can't you adjust the hyperparameter to lower the test error?

```py
def custom_wmae(actual_values, predicted_values):
    weight = actual_values.values / sum(actual_values)
    diff = abs(predicted_values - actual_values.values)
    return np.sum(weight * diff)


param_test1 = { 'max_depth':range(3,10,2),
 'min_child_weight':range(1,6,2)}


xgb1_test1 = xgboost.XGBRegressor(
 learning_rate =0.1,
 n_estimators=140,
 max_depth=5,
 objective ='reg:squarederror',
 min_child_weight = 1,
 subsample=0.8,
 scale_pos_weight=1,
 gamma = 0,
 seed=27)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb1_test1,param_grid= param_test1, cv=5,
                           scoring=make_scorer(custom_wmae, greater_is_better=False),
                           iid=False,
                           return_train_score=True)


params_result= grid_search.fit(shuffled_train_X, shuffled_train_y)
```

- before tuning
  train_error: 0.386055, test_error: 0.674069

-after tuning
train_error: 0.070645, test_error: 0.708254

Comment: What does "before" and "after" tuning mean? The original `xgb1_test1` model configuration is not included in the  grid search, so it is not tried out and could not be found as a better choice. The GridsearchCV does use the  test error *not* the training error to define the better parameter set

Comment: i ues the{'max_defth': 4, 'min_child_weight': 2}. and i also used gridsearch to find the hyperparameter of gamma, subsamples, colsample_bytree, reg_alpha, and the final model of the result is the code below.


xgb1_2 = xgboost.XGBRegressor(
learning_rate =00.1,
n_estimators=5000,
max_defth=4,
objective ='reg:squarederror'
min_child_weight = 2,
subsample=0.9,
colsample_bytree=0.75,
gamma = 0.1,
seed=27)

result= wmae_error(xgb1_2,ewm_df)
print("train_error: %f, test_error: %f"%(result[0], result[1]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the data you are training. If the data you are using for training is quite less, let's say 500 rows and a few columns and even then you are trying to split into training and testing data. The XGBoost is most likely to overfit on the training data.

To make sure your model doesn't overfit, you can try three things -

1. Make sure you have enough data for the XGBoost training. If not, the tendency to overfit will always be there.
2. Play with your parameters. Try introducing regularization to your data, using L1 and L2 regularizations.
3. In the official XGBoost API, you can pass the validation set in the 'xgb.train()' function. So, you can pass your test set in the eval_set parameter of the function.